# convert to LL(k) grammar

Tags: grammar, left-recursion

I was trying to solve a question for practice, but I met a problem when I tried to compare the sample answer with mine. Here is the grammar before conversion:

```
E-> S*
S-> SD
S-> D
D-> [D]
D-> x
```

The start symbol is `E` and the other non-terminal symbols are `S` and `D`.

My answer here is :

```
E-> S*
S-> DS'
S'-> DS'
S'->
D-> [D]
D-> x
```

In the sample answer, they don't have `S-> DS'`, and E becomes `E-> DS'*`. Due to the methods used in the book for removing left recursions,

```
A -> Aa
A -> b

=>  A -> bA'
    A' -> aA'
    A' ->
```

there should be a `S-> DS'`. I'm now getting confused about this, and maybe I just did not understand this method. Could anyone give me any hints about this? And also could you please tell me the meaning of the star symbol `*` here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your answer. The sample answer just simplifies the grammar after transforming it.

```
E -> S*
S -> DS'
```

Given rules for `S'` and `D`, and assuming that `S` and `E` do not occur in other productions, this part of the grammar is equivalent to

```
E -> DS'*
```

The `S` in the first production was simply replaced by `DS'`, as defined in the second production that has been stripped away.

The `*` symbol is possibly a [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). It means that `S` can occur any number of times (including zero). But without context, it's hard to tell, and it could also mean something else.

Comment: Without seeing the text where that example appears, it seems to be unlikely that `S*` is intended to be the Kleene star. First, it would make the grammar ambiguous (because `S` is effectively `D*`) and second because CFGs are not normally written with Kleene stars (hence the recursion in the production for `S`). It seems more likely to me that the text is using `S*` as an idiosyncratic notation for "`S` followed by the end of the input", which most of us would write "`S $`".

Comment: That might well be. It might also mean a literal `*` character. From the information in the question, it's hard to tell. I edited the answer.